# How do I make sense of a vector field defined using and immersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $A$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $f:A\to M$ **(I am unsure if there is a typo in the lecture notes here, would $f:A\to S$ make more sense? )** be an immersion such that $f(A)$ is an open set of the submanifold $S$ containing $p$. If $a \in A$ is such that $f(a)=p$, the vectors $(p,f_i(a))$ form a basis of $T_pS$ and if $(U,x)$ is a chart for $p$ obtained as the inverse of the restriction of $f$ to some open set for $a$, we have that $(p,f_i(a))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ has as vector part $f_i\circ x$ which is just $f_i$ written in terms of $x^1,...,x^d$ instead of $u^1,...,u^d$.

Example :Let's consider for instance the geographic coordinates $\varphi$ and $\theta$ in $S^2\setminus I$ , $I = \{(a,b,c) \in S^2| a \ge 0,b=0)\}$coming from the immersion $f(u,v)=(\cos(u)\sin(v),\sin(u)\sin(v),\cos(v))$ restricted to $A=]0,2\pi[\times]0,\pi[$.
Since
$f_1(u,v)=(-\sin u \sin v,\cos u \cos v,0)$ and $f_2(u,v)=(-\cos u \cos v,\sin u \cos v,-\sin v)$, then
$\partial_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}\equiv (-\sin \varphi \sin \theta,\cos \varphi \cos \theta,0)$
$\partial_2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\equiv (-\cos \varphi \cos \theta,\sin \varphi \cos \theta,-sin \theta)$

I am having trouble understanding this paragraph,even with the example is not clear for me.

**Why do $(p,f_i(a))$ form a basis of $T_pS$ , why is $(p,f_i(a))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$ and why does $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ have as vector part $f_i\circ x$ ?**
It is claimed that $(p,f_i(a))$ is an applied basis vector at point $p$, whose vector part is  $f_i(a)$ I don't get why we need a function $f$ to defined a basis If I wanted a basis for $T_pS$ I would just take the partial derivatives with respect to the coordinates. They also state that $(U,x)$ is a chart for $p$ obtained as the inverse of the restriction of $f$ to some open set for $a$, that is $x:=(f|_A)^{-1}:f(A) \to A, f(A)\subseteq S, A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. from this I guess I have to prove that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}= (f_i)^k\partial_k$, but I am unable to do it.

Can someone please clear these things up?

Comment: Do you have a link to the lecture notes? I am not sure why you replaced $M$ with $S$ and, since $p\in A$, it doesn't make sense to talk about $T_pS$. That should be $T_{f(p)}S$.

Comment: @JohnDouma I could provide it, but it's in italian, I don't know if that is ok for you?

Comment: I thought it made no sense to talk about M, since f(A) is an open set of S and we have T_pS, so M seemed to be out of placed, except for the fact that tehy say S is a submanifold, then we need something bigger , so you say is ok as it was?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't speak Italian but the way I interpreted the first sentence of your post is that $f$ is an immersion from $\mathbb R^n$ to a manifold $M$ and $f(A)$ is contained in the submanifold $S$, where $A$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @JohnDouma I just fixed a typo  $\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of  $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the first sentence., then what you say is ok substituing d instead of n. I hope this was this misunderstanding. d is then the dimension of S, and n the dimension of M